# Como puedo remplazar caracteres con acentuados dentro de una variable en batch

Tags: batch, .bat

estoy empezando a programar en batch y tengo este problema
Si ingreso la variable por argumento no cambia los caracteres acentuados ni la ñ
pero si declaro la variable declaro directamente en el programa si.

```
@echo off 

set variable=%1
set variable=%variable:á=a%
set variable=%variable:é=e%
set variable=%variable:i=a%
set variable=%variable:ñ=n%
echo %variable%

set var=Holáéñ
set var=%var:á=a%
set var=%var:é=e%
set var=%var:ñ=n%
echo %var% 

C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Escritorio\dir>prova holáéñi
holáéña
Holaen
```

Como puedo solucionar esto ??

Gracias.

Comment: Pero esta pregunta ni es `batch`, ni `bash`, ni `spring-batch`, más bien es `powershell`. Considera por favor editar las etiquetas. De cualquier manera, prueba agregando `chcp 65001` al inicio de tu script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema de codificación
te recomiendo para más rápido ir a
**ctrl +  R** y ejecutar **intl.cpl** 
esto abrirá el panel de **Región** 
selecciona la pestaña **Administrativa**
selecciona el botón  **Cambiar configuración Regional**
en la ventana selecciona el check **Usar unicode UTF-8** 

**reinicia**
asi  cmd mostrara los acentos
y si usas  sublime o code al  programar en batch usa  la codificacion ***utf-8*** o ***DOS (cp437)***, asi quedan registrados los acentos y tambien a veces al reabrir un archivo puede recuperarlos.